# Doctrine undefined constant "Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types::ARRAY"

Tags: doctrine, composer-php, doctrine-dbal

Whenever I try to make an entity with the `php bin/console make:entity` command, I get the error when adding a few specific data types like integer.

The error I'm getting is

```
In DoctrineHelper.php line 262:
Undefined constant Doctrine\DBAL\Types\Types::ARRAY
```

This error is caught in the console, it has no stack trace further than this.

I've looked up solutions and found that it has to do with the Doctrine version, though I do not know what to upgrade or downgrade it to since I haven't found a solution for this particular error.

My doctrine versions in composer.json:

```
"doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.11",
"doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.3",
"doctrine/orm": "^3.0",
...
"symfony/doctrine-messenger": "6.4.*",
```

I tried upgrading and downgrading the package but got a compatibility error. What versions should I be using?

Comment: Can you give us your exact version (in your composer.lock) for doctrine-bundle and maker-bundle ?

Comment: Are you sure this problem is related to Composer itself? What have you tried to resolve it? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Are you probably using `doctrine/dbal` in v4? Also, see https://github.com/symfony/maker-bundle/issues/1437 for a potential bug report

Comment: @DylanKAS `doctrine/dbal` is version 4.0.0, `doctrine/doctrine-bundle` is version 2.11.1 and `symfony/maker-bundle` is version 1.53.0.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the presented `require` in composer.json:

```json
{
  "name": "yivi/test_dbal_4",
  "type": "project",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Yivi\\TestDbal4\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.11",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.3",
    "doctrine/orm": "^3.0",
    "symfony/doctrine-messenger": "6.4.*"
  }
}
```

you'll end up installing `doctrine/dbal` version 4 (just released during the weekend).

If you are not ready for the bleeding edge, simply add that you want DBAL 3:

```json
{
  "name": "yivi/test_dbal_4",
  "type": "project",
  "autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
      "Yivi\\TestDbal4\\": "src/"
    }
  },
  "require": {
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "^2.11",
    "doctrine/doctrine-migrations-bundle": "^3.3",
    "doctrine/orm": "^3.0",
    "doctrine/dbal": "^3.8",
    "symfony/doctrine-messenger": "6.4.*"
  }
}
```

With this, you'll install `doctrine/dbal` 3.8, and this particular issue should go away.

You could also accomplish the same by doing `composer require doctrine/dbal:^3.8`.

Also, check if you actually want to install ORM v3, or if you are better served for the time being by remaining on `doctrine/orm:^2`.

Comment: Downgrading to 3.8 worked!

Comment: Downgrading to 3.8 worked for me, but I found I also needed to downgrade doctrine/orm to 2.18 to avoid "Symfony\Bundle\MakerBundle\Util\ClassSourceManipulator::addEntityField(): Argument #2 ($columnOptions) must be of type array" ( "doctrine/orm": "^2.18").
 I presume these two issues are related